# Find all positive $n$ such $a_{n-1}=n^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Assmue that $$\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}a_{i}x^i=\dfrac{1}{1-x-x^2-x^3}$$
Find all postive integer $n$,such
$$a_{n-1}=n^2$$

It is clear $n=1$ such it,But How to find others?

Comment: The coefficients of the LHS are Tribonacci numbers and they have an exponential growth. If follows that $a_{n-1}=n^2$ might hold only for a finite amount of them. In general $a_{n-1}$ will be way larger than $n^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing the power series, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{1-x-x^2-x^3}
&=1+x+2x^2+4x^3+7x^4+13x^5+\cdots\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
where $a_0=1,a_1=1,a_2=2$, and
$$
a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}\tag{2}
$$

Solving the linear recurrence $(2)$, we get
$$
a_n=c_1r_1^n+c_2r_2^n+c_3r_3^n\tag{3}
$$
where $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are the roots of $x^3-x^2-x-1=0$:
$$
\begin{align}
r_1&=1.8392867552141611326\\
r_2&=-0.41964337760708056628+0.60629072920719936926i\\
r_3&=-0.41964337760708056628-0.60629072920719936926i
\end{align}\tag{4}
$$
and $|r_2|=|r_3|=0.73735270576032767520$.

Solving $(3)$ for $n=0,1,2$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
c_1&=0.61841992231939255095\\
c_2&=0.19079003884030372453-0.01870058311173984599i\\
c_3&=0.19079003884030372453+0.01870058311173984599i
\end{align}\tag{5}
$$
and $|c_2|=|c_3|=0.19170433153531949685$.

Thus, for large $n$,
$$
a_n\sim c_1r_1^n\tag{6}
$$
where the error is less than $2\left|c_2r_2^n\right|$. Thus, the error in $(6)$ is less than $\frac25$ for all $n\ge0$.

---

$$
\begin{align}
n^2&=c_1r_1^{n-1}\\
-n\log(r_1)/2\,e^{-n\log(r_1)/2}&=-\sqrt{c_1/r_1}\log(r_1)/2\\
n&=-\frac2{\log(r_1)}\operatorname{W}\left(-\sqrt{c_1/r_1}\log(r_1)/2\right)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Which has two real solutions,
$$
\begin{align}
n_1&=0.7226787371991229401\\
n_2&=9.0000356794115843270
\end{align}\tag{8}
$$
For $n\gt9$, $a_{n-1}$ will be larger than $n^2$.
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n^2&\color{#C00}{1}&4&9&16&25&36&49&64&\color{#C00}{81}&100&121&144\\\hline
a_{n-1}&\color{#C00}{1}&1&2&4&7&13&24&44&\color{#C00}{81}&149&274&504
\end{array}\tag{9}
$$

Comment: Hello,But this is middle school exam problem,so How to use simple methods?

Comment: This seems a bit advanced for a middle school problem. However, to handle this properly, one needs to be able to solve a linear recurrence, which also means using complex numbers.  To show that there are only two places where $a_{n-1}=n^2$, something like Lambert W will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

The other one is $a_8=9^2=81$  This is the generating function for the [tribonacci series](http://oeis.org/A000073), which starts $$1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274, 504, 927, 1705, 3136, 5768, 10609, 19513, 35890, 66012, 121415, 223317, 410744, 755476, 1389537$$  They grow as about $1.8393^n$, so much too fast for there to be another case.